# JavaScript, How to add timeout inside the for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout

This is original code.

```
var randomNumber = [1, 2, 3, 4];

var currentNumber = randomNumber.length

for (i=0; i < currentNumber; i++) {

$("#"+randomNumber[i]).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);

}
```

I want to get the each randomNumber item every 1 second.

Please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my version I first create a shuffled version (`vis`) of the id-array `arr`. Then I `.pop()` one id from it each time the interval function is fired. The interval is cleared when no further id is available in `vis`.

```js
function shfl(arr) { let a=[...arr];
  for (var j,i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {  
   j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1)); 
   [a[i],a[j]]=[a[j],a[i]];
  } return a;
}

const arr=["a1","a2","a3","a4"];
function showdivs(ar){
  var vis=shfl(ar);
  return function(){
    if (vis.length)      
      document.getElementById(vis.pop()).style.visibility="visible";
    else clearInterval(hndl);          
  }
}
const hndl=setInterval(showdivs(arr),1000);
```

```css
#cont div { visibility: hidden }
```

```html
<div id="cont">
<div id="a1">one</div>
<div id="a2">two</div>
<div id="a3">three</div>
<div id="a4">four</div>
</div>
```

One further remark: the function `showdivs()` is a *generator function* that creates a scope for setting up the shuffled array `vis` and then returns the actual function that is called repeatedly under the control of `setInterval()`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const randomNumber = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const currentNumber = randomNumber.length;

for (let i=0; i < currentNumber; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomNumber.length);
    $("#" + random).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
  }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const randomNumber = [1, 2, 3, 4];

setInterval(() => {
    const randomElement = randomNumber[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomNumber.length)];
    console.log(randomElement);
  }, 1000);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 const randomNumber = [1, 2, 3, 4];

for (i=0; i < randomNumber.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#" + randomNumber[i]).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
    }, i * 1000);
  }
```

When calling setTimeout or setInterval , a timer thread in the browser starts counting down and when time up puts the callback function in javascript thread's execution stack. The callback function is not executed before other functions above it in the stack finishes. So in this case the forloop is executing first and then the set timeout starts executing.

So I put some delay and multiply with the element so that when it executes  inside a loop, it will just increase the delay value one after another.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)